# Oracle Benchmarking (SQL_NO_CACHE ...)

Tags: oracle, performance, query-performance

I want to benchmark some queries on an oracle System from a JDBC application.

However, the database seems to cache at some point in time. However, this is not intended in this case.

Is there anything like the MySQL query hint SQL_NO_CACHE.

There are Oracle query hintes `/*+ FULL(test) */` and there is even the `CACHE` hint, but they concern whether the query results goes to the cache at all ...

What can I do on an Oracle System to get rid of any caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an account that has the `ALTER SYSTEM` privilege:

```
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

followed by:

```
alter system flush buffer_cache;
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the results allready better. Though I am not sure yet if nothing else is cached ...